# Accidentally sent BUSD to BUSD contract address

Tags: addresses, recover

I've sent BUSD to the BUSD contract address, instead of my wallet address.
(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56)

Is it possible to get it back?

Answer (score 5):

Wrong place to ask!

Send a message to [Paxos](https://twitter.com/PaxosGlobal?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) on twitter.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I understand now that he is the owner of BUSD.  He doesn't seem to respond on twitter. Is there any other communication channel with him?

Comment: Sorry I am not much help here. Maybe you can try this https://help.paxos.com/hc/en-us?